# Update Postgres ArrayField in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have simple Customer model with `ArrayField`. Does anybody know how I can append new number to this field? (I'm using Django==4.2.7)

```py
# models.py

from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    product_ids = ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), null=True, blank=True
    )
```

Now in Django shell

```py
from from customers.models import Customer

c1 = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
c1.prduct_ids ?????
c1.product_ids = [10] or 10 # will just overwrite not append
# and append will throw the error
c1.product_ids.append(10)
```

Django documentation is very modest on this, just few sentences on how to define filed nothing about update and similar things.

Someone have idea on how to append new integer to this field ones I instantiate individual Customer in shell?

Comment: I'd expect `c1.product_ids` to be a Python array or array-like, so `c1.product_ids.append(42)` ought to work. Ditto `c1.product_ids += [42,43]`. Only at `c1.save()` would the array data be validated for storage into the DB. Try it and see? I haven't actually used it, I'm generalizing from JSONField.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Only thing what I was missing is list as default of the field...I just wrote solution. Thanks in any case!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is answer to my question.

What I was supposed to do is to add default value to my `ArrayFiels` field. And this default value should be empty list as callable (list) not []. Then I also need to remove null=True, blank=True.

Ones this is done and migrated, we can make instance of some individual Customer and use this instance field (product_ids) as normal list (append, extend whatever we want to do).

Here is correct code:

```
models.py


from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

    class Customer(models.Model):
        product_ids = ArrayField(
            models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), default=list
        )
```

Now Django will assign empty list to our `product_ids` and make it ready for normal list methods to be applied.

Then if we go to `django shell`

```
>>> from customer.models import Customer
>>> c1 = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
# Now everthing will work properly 
>>>c1.product_ids.append(1)
>>>c1.save()
```

and that is it...